# psql запрос из файла с русскими символами

Tags: postgresql, psql

Есть запрос вида:

DELETE FROM public.testtable
  WHERE "prefix"='РусскиеСимволы';.

Он хорошо работает в pgAdmin.
Пытаюсь сохранить его в файл и выполнить его через psql.
Но условие не выполняется.
Кодировка БД utf-8, файл сохранен тоже в utf-8.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте менять client_encoding в psql и/или кодировку в консоли. На винде с этим всё плохо. В консоли одна кодировка, в БД другая, в клиенте - может быть даже третья. Правда, после манипуляций оно может заработать, но при этом сломать вывод psql в консоли.